# how Set object in paremeter

Tags: javascript, function, class, object

I'm trying to pass an class object thru function parameter for example

```
    class Monster {
      constructor() {
        this.position = {
          x: 20,
          y: 20
        }
}
      };
      class Player {
        constructor() {
          this.position = {
            x: 20,
            y: 20
          }
}
        };
    
        const monster = new Monster();
        const player = new Player();
    
        function collision(object_one, object_two) {
          console.log(object_one.position.x);
          console.log(object_two.position.x);
        };
    
        //calling function in buffer:
    
        collision(player, monster);
```

I want to make a collision function so i don't have to write the same code over and over.
the collision function should return true or false when objects make contact.

Comment: You're missing closing `}` on your classes.

Comment: Consistent use of indentation and other whitespace will make your code more human-readable, which will help you as a human read it and spot structural errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had syntax error

```js
class Monster {
  constructor() {
    this.position = {
      x: 20,
      y: 20
    }
  };
}
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.position = {
      x: 20,
      y: 20
    }
  };
}

const monster = new Monster();
const player = new Player();

function collision(object_one, object_two) {
  console.log(object_one.position.x);
  console.log(object_two.position.x);
  return object_one.position.x === object_two.position.x && object_one.position.y === object_two.position.y
};

//calling function in buffer:

console.log(collision(player, monster));
```